# DELPHI Indy SSL POST mystic

Tags: delphi, post, ssl, indy

I have a program, which posts some form data to .asp script via SSL. On my and two other computers (2x win7, one WinXP) - .asp script returns positive answer, the data that was posted is accepted. But from another two computers (win7, winXP) .asp script does not accepts post data, but every input is filled as asked. idHTTP successfully connects via SSL, posts data, script gets that data and parse it, but for some reason does not accepts it. Everything works fine on all computers when using GET method. The problem occurs only when using POST method.

Comment: Please show the actual data that is being posted, the actual code that is doing the posting, and the Delphi and Indy version numbers that are being used. There is no way to diagnose this issue without seeing what the server is receiving and rejecting.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. :-) What does "does not accept it" mean? Are you getting an error code returned? An exception? Do you have the same SSL libraries installed on all the machines? What version of Indy? What version of the SSL libraries? There's not much information here to use to try and help you, I'm afraid. Can you edit your question to add more details? Thanks. :-)

Comment: I'm using Delphi7 with Indy 9.00.10
OpenSSL libraries are the same (included with app), I'm using idhttp.post('URL', query, result). query is a TString, and a POST variables are added like that:
query.text := 'username=username&password=password&forminput=value', where values are assigned as form asks. Application doesnt show any error code or exception (as I mentioned before, server gets that POST data and understands it).asp script is scripted to show error if occurs, for example empty input value. But it shows, that all input values are parsed correctly, but for some reason not accepted.